# How can I make an HTML embed element size to the content of its source

Tags: html

I embedded a pdf with this code into my html:

```
<embed src="test.pdf">
```

Now I want that to have the whole pdf displayed.

Is there something like `width: fit-content height: fit-content` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<embed src="file_name.pdf" width=800px height=2100px>
```

Can define Height and Width in this manner. Either use px amount or use a percentage.

```
<embed src="file_name.pdf" width="100%"height="100%">
```

for the whole page.

Comment: Percentage not allowed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all